# Ayuda con query sql server 2008 pls

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `usuarios` la cual tiene varios campos, uno de ellos es el campo `estado_usuario` el cual tiene como parámetro 0, significa el usuario esta deshabilitado y 1 el cual significa que el usuario esta vigente.

Necesito contar la cantidad de usuario vigentes y no vigentes pero no sé si es posible que me muestre ambos en 1 query.

por ahora solo puedo obtener en 2 query la cantidad respectiva de cada estado de vigencia

```
SELECT COUNT(ESTADO_USUARIO) FROM USUARIOS WHERE ESTADO_USUARIO= 0; <--- (me da 150)

SELECT COUNT(ESTADO_USUARIO) FROM USUARIO WHERE ESTADO_USUARIO= 1; <----- (me da 320)
```

La idea es como decía anteriormente obtener ambos resultados en 1 query, pero no sé como podría hacerlo... también podría ser un procedimiento almacenado.

Mi motor de base de datos es SQL SERVER 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT estado_usuario, count(estado_usuario) from usuarios group by estado_usuario
```

Tienes que usar `GROUP BY` que agrupa las filas seleccionadas por los campos que aparecen en la cláusula `GROUP BY`. Estos grupos devuelven una única fila por grupo, en es te caso te devolvería cada estado con su total respectivamente.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar tu respuesta?

Comment: No veo que en la respuesta +1 se haya explicado el funcionamiento del GROUP BY y sin embargo no es voto negativo, mas parcialidad por favor.

Comment: El usuario que dio ese +1 tendrá sus motivos y razones por haberlo otorgado, realmente no fui yo.

Comment: Gracias juan, justo lo que necesitaba :D.

Comment: Por favor, explica tu respuesta. No es solamente contestar al usuario que pregunto, si no a futuros usuarios. Mira [answer]

Answer (score 4):

Debes investigar sobre usar `GROUP BY` en funciones de agregación. En este caso, la consulta sería simplemente:

```
SELECT  Estado_Usuario,
        COUNT(*) Usuarios
FROM dbo.Usuarios
GROUP BY Estado_Usuario
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar lo que necesitan , es necesario compreder el uso de los agrupadores como el group by y el HAVING, así como las funciones de agreción como el COUNT, el MAX, AVGT, etc. En este caso se necesita sumar y agrupar los resultados, así que te mostrará la suma de los status diferentes que existan.

```
SELECT estado_usuario, COUNT(estado_usuario) 
    from usuarios 
group by estado_usuario.
```

Dejo un enlace para futuras referencias

http://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2016/02/group-by-having-y-su-funcion-agregada_2.html